# Issues with fitting a variogram

Tags: normal-distribution, autocorrelation, variogram

I am trying to fit a spherical variogram to some synthetic data using the code available at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25948-variogramfit. However, I have some doubts. I simulated some synthetic data using GMRF with the defined graph structure. I mean, I generated some samples where each sample is a multivariate gaussian distribution over space. I then took pairwise semi variances and got the overall semivariogram.

I then fit the model variogram to this empirical one. This is what I got. However, I have some doubts, when I generated the synthetic data it had no noise. So I was assuming no nugget effect. However, I am seeing significant nugget effect why is it so. I just drew samples from a multivariate gaussian distribution over space.

I have a spatial grid of size 10x10, the variables in this form a multivariate gaussian distribution. Any suggestions?

I am not sure but the more samples I add, and calculate the pair wise semi variance, the nugget starts increasing. Even though the empirical semi variogram is smoother, the nugget starts appearing more. What is the reason behind this?

[image]

Comment: For this question to become answerable you will need to supply the details of your simulation and your variogram construction. However, I see *no* evidence of a nonzero nugget: although your *fit* has a nugget, the *data* do not. You can check that yourself by generating values at sets of closely-spaced points (thereby filling in the values between lags of 0 and 1).

Comment: @whuber. Actually, I used a software to make the fit http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25948-variogramfit. It allows me to specify whether or not to add nugget when I fit a model variogram. I fits the variogram by minimizing the least squares error. If I don't fit the nugget it will be zero. But if I allow it to have the nuggets, it comes like this. Actually, I specified a gaussian markov random field by its precision matrix so that every node is connected to its 3x3 neighborhood. From this precision matrix, I got the $\Sigma$ matrix and then sampled from the gaussian.

Comment: @whuber. I then took pairwise distances between the points and got the semi variance to calculate the empirical variogram. Then fit an exponential variogram to the empirical one